# Is the boundary of a smooth surface a regular smooth curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a [smooth surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothSurface.html) and let $\partial S$ be its boundary (and assume it is not empty). Is $\partial S$ necessarily piecewise regular and piecewise $C^1$ smooth?

Thanks!

(It seems like this is the case in all of the trivial examples, such as a triangle and its boundary, half a sphere and its boundary which is a circle, etc... I was wondering if there are any examples in which this is not the case )

Comment: That is a very imprecise definition of a smooth surface. In particular, they don't address any boundary points at all. In modern mathematics, if someone has a smooth surface with boundary, that is is interpreted to mean that the boundary is a smooth curve. Otherwise we say specifically "piecewise-smooth boundary" or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Any open set in the plane is easily found to be a regular surface. Its boundary need not be locally rectifiable. Consider for example the region bounded by the von Koch snowflake curve.

Comment: Thanks Alex!!!!